# update column based on values in another (SAS, SQL)

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table with 2 columns, I need to update one of them based on values in another.

Column A is a flag  (1s and 0s), column B is a string column. I need update column B based on the flag in column A. If A = 1 then column B needs to preserve its values, if column A is 0, I need to set column B to blank.

```
column A.    Column B.      
1            abc         <-keep
0            abc         <-set to blank
1            abc         <-keep


PROC SQL;
update table abc
set column B = 
case when A.column IS NOT NULL then A.column = A.column
else A.column = ' '
end
```

Comment: A [mcve] would make this clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply using `Update` with `CASE` statement to do what you want:

> update column B based on the flag in column A. If A = 1 then column B
> needs to preserve its values, if column A is 0, I need to set column B
> to blank.

```sql
UPDATE
  your_table
SET
  column_B = CASE
            WHEN column_A = 1 THEN column_B -- columnB needs to preserve its value
            ELSE ''  -- set column B to blank.
  END;
```

Before:

```
column_A    column_B
1           abc
0           abc
1           abc
```

After `update`:

```
column_A    column_B
1           abc
0           
1           abc
```

[**dbfiddle DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/B1uYstLZ)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand the question very well but the solution seems quite simple to me:

```
UPDATE abc
   SET b = ''
 WHERE a = 0;
```

Please note that column B remains unchanged not only if column A has value 1 but also when that column equals NULL or contains whatever value different from 0.